# compiler doesn't see the second for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to change random character in string randomly. Also program will decide how many character will change randomly. Compiler doesn't see the second for loop. I don't know why? Thank you again

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char string[10];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Please enter string: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    for (a = 0; string[a] != '\0'; a++) {
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i + rand() % count) {
        string[i];
    }
    printf("String is: %s ", string);
}
```

Comment: `i+rand()%count` does nothing. and `string[i];` does nothing either. all that doesn't matter since `string` isn't declared.

Comment: What is this `i+rand()%count` doing in second `for` loop?

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the second `for` statement is also wrong.

Comment: Ömer, when asking questions like this, please always provide a _complete program_ that we can compile and run ourselves.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What do you think `string[i];` in the second "loop" does - anything?

Comment: I declared it but in the global area. I didn't write it here but I declared in compiler. I am trying to change characters in string. But program will decide how many character will be chenge. so randomly

Comment: `i <= count;` ==> `i < count;`

Comment: ok I will complete now

Comment: The `;` at the end of the line in `for (int i = 0; i <= count; i+rand()%count);` completes the `for` statement. If you remove it, you will see the loop work correctly.

Comment: I tried it, but still have a same problem

Comment: Replace `i+rand()%count` with `i+=rand()%count` in order to increment `i`. Replace `string[i];`with for example `string[i] = 'A';`in order to change the char in the string.

Comment: As written, the second loop is an infinite loop that does nothing.

Comment: thank you so much :) I tried it and it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose a random `char` in a word and replace it with a random `char` you can try the following.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char string[10];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Please enter string: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    for (a = 0; string[a] != '\0'; a++) {
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
    char randomletter = 'a' + (random() % 26);
    string[rand() % count] = randomletter;
    printf("String is: %s ", string);
}
```

Test

```
Please enter string: foobar
6
String is: fooiar
```

Test 2

```
Please enter string: zoobar
6
String is: zolbar
```